# Google and the lowest common denominator

Tags: discussion

What do we feel about questions for novices?

> "What is Ohm's law?"
>
> "Explain the difference between AC and
>   DC"

Would we be replicating the Wikipedia page?

Would multiple overlapping answers be a good or bad thing?

Would beginner questions be doing someone's homework for them?

I would be in favour of these questions - so long as they were Community Wiki, with a cultivated answer leading to more detailed questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is difficult to set a hard limit on how "entry-level" a question should be allowed. Ideally, if asked in good faith, there *should be no* lower limit. All questions are welcome. But it is reasonable to require some small sense of due diligence from the original author. **Simple questions, good; Lazy questions, bad.**

The question has to be taken in context. It is very likely that questions posed the way you quoted are *not* being asked in good faith. I would urge everyone to read this blog post: [**Asking the First Questions**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/area-51-asking-the-first-questions/).

> It has long been established that no question is too entry-level nor too basic. Everyone is welcome. But, in these earliest days, we are DESIGNING a site for experts. To attract experts, you need a site where people are asking very interesting and challenging questions, not the basic questions found on every other Q&A site. Remember, the pro sites WILL attract the enthusiasts, but not the other way around!
>
> **The earliest questions on a site will set the tone and topic of the site for a long time.**

The blog post linked above talks about the issue of *seeding* the site with questions… in a bad way. No one who spent more than 10 seconds on their problem likely to craft a lazy question simply stated as "What is ohms law?" However, if a user comes along with a genuine problem, explaining it in sufficient detail, forming a well-thought-out question — even if the underlying question turns out to be extremely basic — it should be allowed.

As a matter of fact, it is the simplest questions that provide opportunities for the most thorough, thought-provoking answers. It should be answered with the most awesome answer you can muster. It should become **THE canonical source** for that information on the internet. That's what the site is for.

Comment: The canonical source for that kind of information on the Internet is Wikipedia, not Stack Exchange.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:What_Wikipedia_is_not#Wikipedia_is_not_a_manual.2C_guidebook.2C_textbook.2C_or_scientific_journal Stack Exchange is the canonical source for questions and answers about specific, unencyclopedic things.

Comment: Thanks Robert, that clears things up

Comment: @Endolith, just because wikipedia has very thorough answers on many basic subjects does not meant hat SE cannot also. The further I have gone into EE the less Wiki has helped me.

Comment: @ Kortuk: Yes, that's what I'm saying. Wiki is for encyclopedic overview stuff like "what is a resistor?", stackexchange is for answers to specific detailed questions like "which value resistor do i use in this circuit?"

Comment: @Endolith, the definition that wikipedia has for most things will be geared for the general public, while here it can be geared for what a electronics tinker or professional would like to see. What is a resistor is not a perfect case, but a PID controller is probably a good subject that our answer here would be more useful to a tinkerer or technical professional in electronics.

Comment: @Endolith, Please do not misunderstand me though, I agree in general with what you mean, but when I close vote I fully close a question, I cannot take part in giving a community vote, if I agree with users and 2 or 4 vote to close I will normally finish it up. I just will not be the first unless the question must be closed(Clearly violates basic rules). Normally on the others I wait for people based on how strongly I think it violates rules, if there are 4 votes then I can act as a normal user and cast the 5th.

Comment: @Endolith, with these questions it is normally just a case of downvotes though unless they just give no detail and it is too broad.

Answer (score 3):

Lazy questions should get downvotes, not closed?  Then they can revise them to ask something better?

Comment: or choose to close it, again being important that lazy and easy are differentiated.

Answer (score 2):

If the question can be totally answered with a link to Wikipedia/by cut-and-pasting part of the article, it should be closed as it is too broad.

If the question is diving into any specifics, sure, ask away.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with Robert, I also would like to point out that the term **expert** won't have the same meaning to everyone.

Also don't forget that explaining something in layman's terms requires a thorough understanding of the subject and therefore is best done by an **expert**.

But the **expert** himself is often the least likely to ask any questions, because he has learned how to solve his own problems. If you don't want a site that's starving for question, you also need the users that are looking for expert answers.